# How to get proxy response in java http request?

Tags: java, http, curl, proxy, apache-httpclient-4.x

I send http request through a proxy server.

When I use `curl` I get two parts of the response: from proxy and  from destination server:

```
curl -i --proxy proxy.com:8080 --proxy-user user:1234 https://target.com

HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
X-Proxy-Header: Header-Value: connected established

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: target.com
other headers
http response
```

How can I get the same output in Java? I use apache HttpClient and it returns only the response from destination server. Proxy response is missing.

I need the basic idea rather than concrete implementation, because I have to reuse it for Netty library too. Anyway, example code to start from:

```
HttpHost myProxy = new HttpHost("proxy.com", 8080);
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
credentialsProvider.setCredentials(new AuthScope(myProxy), new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "1234"));
HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
                .setConnectionManager(new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager())
                .setProxy(myProxy)
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)                    
                .build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse = client.execute(response);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need the basic idea rather than concrete implementation

Well, the idea is based on a fact that java libraries perform all low-level stuff under the hood. In case with proxy connection, the typical workflow for HTTPS request can be:

1. client connects to proxy machine
2. proxy machine establishes the connection to destination server and returns `200 Connection established` and then transmits all traffic between client and destination over SSL
3. client encrypts request with public key and later things go as usual

The second part of workflow is handled by java libraries as well as all other stuff.

For netty library, proxies are handled with [ProxyHandler](http://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/handler/proxy/ProxyHandler.html) since 4.1. Proxy response can be processed using custom proxy handler in `handleResponse` method or by adding additional inbound handler to pipeline.

I did not search solutions for Apache HttpClient, but at least all traffic can be seen if logging is set to debug level. It can be achieved with:

```
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.Log","org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SimpleLog");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.showdatetime", "true");
System.setProperty("org.apache.commons.logging.simplelog.log.org.apache.http.wire", "DEBUG");
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I get the same output in Java?

One way would be to doing the proxying yourself using an `HTTPClientConnection` object.

Another way would be to implement your own version of the `HttpClientConnectionManager` API that captures and saves the proxy responses.

However, it is not going to be easy ... and I don't really see the point.  If you are just trying to see what is being sent and received for debugging purposes, then a simpler approach is to use Apache HttpClient logging as described here:

- https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/logging.html

You can even get Apache to go everything that goes "over the wire".

Comment: Yes, this looks too complicated. Actually I need the value of the X-Proxy-Header. Logging is not enough for me, but I guess logging works on listeners/interceptors. I'll try to find if it's possible to attach to them.